# Pin an SVG Element in Position when the Window Resizes

Tags: html, css, svg, position

I have an SVG triangle that i'm using as a "wedge" effect on a site.  However, when I reduce the window size the SVG moves out of place.

I've attached an image (below) of how it is supposed to look as well as the codepen link below.

Does anyone know how I can have this effect so it stays pinned in place when the window resizes?

It's driving me insane.

codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/LrgwZV

Emily

**Image of how it supposed to look:**

[image]

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.section {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 3.583rem 0;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 9;
}

.background-block-left-top {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #162f45;
    top: 57px;
}

.two-col {
    padding:8.916rem 2.074rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    background: wheat;
}

.two-col.col-2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background: #2b67f3;
    width: 85.5%;
    min-width: 0;
}

#wedge{
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  top: 23px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is anonther idea with less of code and with gradient to create the triangle:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3.583rem 0;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 9;
}

.two-col {
  padding: 8.916rem 2.074rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 37.5%;
  background: red;
}

.two-col.col-2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;  
  position: relative;
  background: #2b67f3;
  width: 62.5%;
  min-width: 0;
}
.two-col.col-1:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;
    right: 62.5%;
    left: -100vw;
    height: calc(50% + 150px);
    background: 
      linear-gradient(to top right,#162f45 49.5%,transparent 50%) top/100% 150px no-repeat, 
      linear-gradient(#162f45,#162f45) 0 150px/100% 100% no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div id="row-2" class="row">
    <div class="two-col col-1"></div>
    <div class="two-col col-2">
      <div class="folio-wrap">
        <h2 class="tl">LOREM IPSUM</h2>
        <p class="tl">Performant, secure and search engine optimised sites and applications. Inset covers content managment, commerce sites or a brochure site to promote a product or service.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Another alternative is to change the position of the SVG to make it inside the element used as background and adjust its position:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3.583rem 0;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 9;
}

.background-block-left-top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #162f45;
  top: 57px;
}

.two-col {
  padding: 8.916rem 2.074rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.two-col.col-2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #2b67f3;
  width: 85.5%;
  min-width: 0;
}

#wedge {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom:100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="background-block-left-top">
  <svg id="wedge" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 692 49"><polygon fill="#162f45" points="0 0 0 49 692 49 "/></svg>
  </div>
  <div id="row-2" class="row">
    <div class="two-col col-1"></div>
    <div class="two-col col-2">
      <div class="folio-wrap">
        <h2 class="tl">LOREM IPSUM</h2>
        <p class="tl">Performant, secure and search engine optimised sites and applications. Inset covers content managment, commerce sites or a brochure site to promote a product or service.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow.  That's amazing. Would you be able to explain what's going on there? Because the background property is written in shorthand I can't understand how that works or how you've got the positioning to work. I'm hugely impressed !!

Comment: @TheChewy as you can see I used multiple background (separated by a comma) the first one will create the triangle, it's placed on the top with a height of 150px and 100% width. The second one is a square shape with 100% height/width shifted by 150px to the bottom (the height of the triangle). And of course both of them should not repeat ;)

Comment: @TheChewy for the postionning, the pseudo-element is positonned relative the to the whole row. The top should be negative (the height of triangle), the height is 50% like you want but we add the 150px of the top. the left should be a big value to have the overflow and the right is the width of the second col to make it in the middle of both columns

Comment: Thanks Temani.  That's so impressive.  The one slight spanner in the works is that on the site there are other instances where I need to do this with shapes that can't be created with CSS gradients.  So I'm kind of still in the same situation.  I believe I can donate reputation points to people, so I'll send 20 your way for such an excellent answer / explanation. I'm still stuck in a bit of hole though, so will still need to try and find a way of doing this with inline svg.

Comment: @TheChewy in this case you need to make your question more generic ;) because here we answer specific questions and none will know that this is a more generic issue.

Comment: ...but my question is generic. It says 'Pin an SVG element in position when the window re-sizes'?

Comment: @TheChewy yes but the situation is particular ... you provided a code, so we can provide a fix to that code .. if you change the layout the fix will change ... so I cannot give you a generic way to do if you will have other shapes and other situations.

Comment: although actually I suppose it does look like I would accept another answer relating to the triangle specifically.  I'll repost another question and mark this as correct.

Comment: Thanks for adding the other method, much appreciated.